# Why doesn't fire flow back INTO the cylinder?

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, diffusion

Let us take into a consideration a (pressurized) kerosene stove.

The pressure drives fuel out of the nozzle, like

[image: Primus Burner]

or in a much simpler arrangement as in

[image: this one]

**Question-**

Why doesn't fire flow back into the fuel cylinder from the stove's burner tip, via the fuel inlet at the very bottom; what *interface thingy* keeps fire ignited only above the burner.

P.S. I have never seen an LPG powered stove, but I am sure that besides the difference of self-pressurized fuel cylinder & valves- the burners work in a pretty similar manner.

I can't find appropriate tags for this question, so I am open to suggestions about them also :)

Comment: This is interesting.

Answer (score 2):

A flammable liquid in its liquid state will not burn, you can throw matches into a bucket of liquid petrol all day long without a problem. its only when you get gas/vapour coming off it that you gotta run

ABSOLUTELY DO NOT TRY TO TEST THE ABOVE EXPERIMENT

I know you know but just to be sure (not being smart with you) its LPG in the cylinder, Liquefied petroleum gas , so you don't need any device where you think there should be one.

Comment: :) Agreed, but when LPG cylinder is about to get finished, the liquid would have almost converted to gases/fumes; for instance you may have heard pilots saying "... we are **running on fumes**, request immediate landing permission..." when low on fuel

Comment: "A flammable liquid in its liquid state will not burn" - is that *generally* true or just for petrol / kerosene?

Comment: .... which is almost always, since there is a petrol vapour/ air mix hovering above the liquid. Your answer's perfectly right when properly qualified, I just don't want someone to try this at home.

Comment: @Xarennarcy true for all liquified flammable gases

Comment: @XerenNarcy What I believe Irish physics is saying is that to burn, something needs both fuel and an oxidiser, in this case oxygen from the air. If the cylinder contained even propane in its gaseous state alone, a match to the neck of the cylinder would only ignite the propane at the top. Any burning reaction entering the cylinder would be quenched by the lack of oxygen. But watch out when oxygen diffuses into the cylinder.

Comment: @user4453945 i've flown planes, running on fumes is an expression of the pilot's fear that he will not be given an immediate landing spot by ATC, (luckly not the literal truth)...still needs more thought tho

Comment: Yep, fair point. I had in mind flashpoints of liquid fuels, that _eventually_ a liquid fuel can ignite from sufficient heat alone / without the vapor igniting first. I don't know the physics there too well though...

Comment: @XerenNarcy same here, I don't know the physics of blowing tanks but always seen propane tankers blow up on *Destroyed in Seconds*. So whatever it is, its real

Comment: @Wet thanks for your comment/warning about gas/air mix earlier. I should have issued the standard "kids, don't try this at home " disclaimer, I'm still learning regards

Comment: Just to clarify: petrol (approximately iso-octane) has a high partial pressure, so an open bucket of the stuff will quickly form fuel air mixture above the surface.  At room temperature, the vaporization will be so fast that the mixture will be too fuel rich to burn directly above the surface. But somewhere between the liquid and open air, there will be a mixture. If you throw a match at it you should absolutely expect it to flash and it will almost certainly catch fire.

Answer (score 1):

It takes more than kerosene to burn.  You need kerosene *and oxygen*.  The flame does not go back further into the cylinder because there is no oxygen there to allow it to burn.

Answer (score 0):

The cylinder is pressurised. It's pushing kerosene out quickly, so oxygen can't get in.

Comment: But then please consider the case of the rocket engines, their design is beautifully simple - just a monstrous fuel pump - how come they are safe when operating in space & in atmosphere.

Comment: rocket engine uses liquid O and liquid H right up to the tip of the burners and these liquids dont burn (my best guess, pretty sure they don't), so no "blowback" into the rocket tanks

Comment: And also, the oxygen and fuel are stored in separate tanks, and only mixed at the engine, so even if they were in gaseous state, they wouldn't burn there.

Answer (score 0):

Combustion is a chemical reaction and for this to happen you need the molecules to be sufficiently near to each other for the electrical forces to take over and cause the reaction. Thus you need to atomize the fuel and mix it well with air/oxygen in the presence of heat (= highly energetic molecules to bring collisions). This is why you have a long column of fuel in the jet just before reaching the hot spot(plate) without experiencing much of a combustion. As the liquid fuel hits the hot metal spot (note you need to give heat at the start by other means) it splashes, gets heated then mixed with air then react.
The same happens around the wick of a candle in a slow version of this. The hot wick (heated at the start by a match stick) heats the fuel and atomizes it which then gets mixed with the entrained air/oxygen then reaction starts.
In oxy-gas fule systems for welding, you can have a case of the flame travelling back into the fuel cylinder causing explosion- since in this case you already have atomized mixtures and the little heat needed to start the reaction is carried out by the flame front. For this reason you need what is called 'flame suppressors' (one way valves in essence) to stop such accidents.

Answer (score -1):

Why because any fuel can't fire without the helping of oxygen and when the fuel and oxygen mixed together and it will be converted into heat state i mean it is utilized and there fuel will not be there, So again and again it will be utilized (i.e loss of fuel) so that only there's no way to return fire into the cylinder and also the inside pressure is more than the out side pressure so never the fire will not entry into the cylinder definitely it goes upward position, that is it.